# cmake doesn't find Qt5

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, cmake

Last night I tried to download the disassembler called "Evan's debugger (edb)", that has similar GUI to Ollydbg (Linux only).

I tried to build them via terminal using:

```
sudo cmake ../edb_folder
```

With `../edb_folder` being the directory containing edb's source code.

It gives me the following error about Qt5:

```
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Checking for module 'libgvc>=2.38.0'
-- 
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Svg" with any
of the following names:
Qt5SvgConfig.cmake
qt5svg-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Svg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Qt5Svg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5Svg"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
src/CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kanna/Desktop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

But I already have Qt5 installed on my system (see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqLY9.png)). Why can't cmake find Qt5?

(FYI: I'm using ubuntu 64bits)

Answer (score 3):

go to synaptic and install libqt5svg5 + libqt5svg5-dev + libqt5svg5-private-dev